# Programação de um botão que ao clicar pela 2ª vez, o form retorna á posiçao anterior

Tags: c#

Boas pessoal.

Eu tenho um programa em C# com vários forms criados. Cada form tem FormBorderStyle:None e tem um botão que ao clicar maximiza o form.

O que pretendo é que ao clicar nesse mesmo botão pela segunda vez, o form voltar ao tamanho e posição anterior. Com faço isso?

Cumprimentos,
EntryWay.

Comment: Não conhecendo o código fica mais difícil ajudar, mas tem varias formas de fazer isso, a mais fácil e gravar essa informação em  json e no segundo click fazer set das propriedades with e heigt

Answer (score 0):

Tem várias formas de fazer isso. Segue um exemplo:

O código abaixo é de um `Form` inteiro. Criei o mesmo apenas para teste. Lembre-se de adaptar o mesmo com o seu código que já existe no seu `Form`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int _clicks = 1;
    private int _originalWidth;
    private int _originalHeight;
    private Point _originalPosition;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(_clicks == 1)
        {
            _originalHeight = Height;
            _originalWidth = Width;
            _originalPosition = Location;
        }

        if(_clicks == 2)
        {
            Width = _originalWidth;
            Height = _originalHeight;
            Location = _originalPosition;
            _clicks = 0;
        }

        _clicks++;
    }
}
```

- No primeiro `Click` do `Button`, a largura, altura e posição do `Form` são salvas.
- No segundo `Click` do `Button`, os valores salvos anteriormente são restaurados e o `Form` volta a ter as mesmas dimensões iniciais e a mesma posição. O contador de clicks (`_clicks`) é resetado e volta a se comportar como se nenhum `Click` tenha sido executado.